# Error defining modules using browserify

Tags: angularjs, npm, browserify

I am not sure I am doing it the right way. I have defined modules the following:

```
require('angular');
require('angular-ui-router');
var $ = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');
```

I have my package.json file like this:

```
{
  "name": "web",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "browserify main.js -o bundle.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^12.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.4.8",
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.2.15",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "bootstrap-social": "^4.11.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.5.0",
    "jquery": "^2.1.4"
  }
}
```

And my html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrap">
            <!--header-->
            <div ui-view="header"></div>
            <!--main content-->
            <div ui-view="content"></div>
        </div>

        <!--push the footer down-->
        <div id="push"></div>

        <!--footer-->
        <div ui-view="footer"></div>

        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="commonViews/commonView.js"></script> //angular module defined
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run the html page, I get an error in console saying "angular is not defined"

What I am doing wrong? I have run the command `browserify maing.js -o bundle.js` which minified all the code into bundle.js file and yet still the same error. Apart from that I am not able to bundle bootstrap and font-awesome css files. Is it true that broswerify doesn't support css files?

Comment: Where do you first use angular? There is a chance if you include angular as a module it doesn't get exposed in the global scope.

Comment: @hege_hegedus I am using angular in `commonView.js` file. I guess it should pull angular from `bundle.js` file build using browserify right?

Comment: try inserting `var angular = require('angular');` at the beginning of `commonView.js`

Comment: @hege_hegedus Changed the same to webpack and its working fine for angular except for jquery and bootstrap css and font-awesome css files

Comment: browserify cannot pack css